# Redirect a form to .load() of jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

We load certain (sub)page with jQuery `.load()`.

This subpage contains several forms.

I want that instead redirecting to the `action` of the form, clicking Submit should `.load()` the output of the responding script replacing the subpage with the form.

To make the problem harder, one of the forms has `onsubmit` attribute:

`onsubmit="$.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(msg){if(msg!='') alert(msg); else alert('Data should update in a few minutes.')}); return false"`

What is the easiest way to solve my problem?

Comment: they'd all have to use ajax, and then you simply replace the content of your container with the response. relatively simple, but with a large chance of unwanted side effects you'd have to work through along the way.

Comment: @KevinB The question is how to make it use AJAX without modifying the form code (somehow by manipulating `onsubmit` handlers or so)

Comment: i mean, that's certainly *possible*, good luck with that. it's gonna be a lot of work overriding all the possible ways that forms could be handled given that onsubmit is one of them in your case. If you can't modify the html/js of the forms you're overriding, you're going to have a very hard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a good enough solution:

```
function my_submit_handler() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(data){$('#main-board').html(data)});
}

$(function(){
    $('form').submit(my_submit_handler);
});
```

I also replaced `return false` with `event.preventDefault(); event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the `onsubmit` attribute of the loaded HTML subpage, in order to prevent `my_submit_handler` to run if the user answers "No".

Comment: doesn't this cause a double submit in the case of the onsubmit="$.post(...)"? oh, no it doesn't, it just doesn't run your global handler.